# jQuery Freichat conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I'm trying to integrate the freichat module to my website, but i got this error

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

I tried to encapsulate it with an anonymous function passing jQuery as the parameter , like this:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // my custom code
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I also put `jQuery` instead of `$` and got the below issue:

```
jQuery is undefined
```

Any idea regarding this?

Comment: show complete code and add jquery file properly

Answer (score 0):

Add JQuery library to your document:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already added the library in local:      <script src="JS/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: check in website that file is called correctly or not. just add above live link then check work or not If work means check your local jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

Codes:

```
    <script src="JS/jquery.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#lawyerrr").select2();
      $("#fromm").select2(); 
      $("#too").select2(); 
      });
    </script>

  <?php
   $ses = null; // Return null if user is not logged in 
   if (!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $loggedUser = $_SESSION['user'];
   }
  if(isset($loggedUser['idd']))
  { 
    if($loggedUser['idd'] != null) // Here null is guest 
   { 
   $ses=$loggedUser['idd']; //LOOK, now userid will be passed to FreiChat 
  } 
} 
//echo $ses;
if(!function_exists("freichatx_get_hash")){
function freichatx_get_hash($ses){

       if(is_file("C:/wamp64/www/freichat/hardcode.php")){

               require "C:/wamp64/www/freichat/hardcode.php";

               $temp_id =  $ses . $uid;

               return md5($temp_id);

       }
       else
       {
               echo "<script>alert('module freichatx says: hardcode.php file not
found!');</script>";
       }

       return 0;
}
}

 ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascipt" src="http://localhost/freichat/client/main.php?id=<?php echo $ses;?>&xhash=<?php echo freichatx_get_hash($ses); ?>"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/freichat/client/jquery/freichat_themes/freichatcss.php" type="text/css">
```

Comment: open your browser dev console (usually F12) and check if it REALLY finds `JS/jquery.js` on your server